# Why is PCN (Pavement Classification Number) not included in Jeppesen Terminal charts?

Tags: airport, jeppesen

Pavement Classification Number goes hand in hand with Aircraft Classification Number (PCN/ACN).

To calculate ACN, it is required for destination airport surfaces such as runway, taxiways & aprons to be of Rigid or Flexible pavement type and PCN number helps to determine whether the aircraft can use the surfaces

Jeppesen Terminal charts has "Taxiway Compatibility" diagram under 10-9B where it says about Codes A to F (wing span & OMGWS (Outer Main Gear Wheel Span)) and nothing about the pavement surface type & its compatibility or under "Airport Briefing" -> "Taxi Procedures".
[image: Taxiway Compatibility - VIDP (Source: Internet)]

My questions are:

1. Should we assume that if for eg. Taxiways are compatible for Code C, then its PCN will be definitely equal to/higher than ACN ?.
2. Jeppesen Terminal Charts doesn't mention about Runway's & Apron compatibility with Aircraft codes (A to F) or it's PCN. How are we supposed to know whether a stand (under a particular apron) can accommodate certain types of aircraft of a given weight and tyre pressure (PCN) ?.
3. Where can I find Aerodrome Reference Code (to help determine if the runway can be used by aircraft) ?.